# Batch- cmd stating strings as numbers?

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, set

I'm making a Batch RPG with an inventory system, and I want to make it so that when the user equips a weapon they have it changes the currentweapon string to the weapon they equipped (in this case, a Tachi sword). When the program runs and I equip the weapon, it changes current weapon from Fists (the default) to 0. What's happening?

Here is the code:

```
:Inventory
cls
echo Type the number to equip the weapon (Type back to return home)
echo Equipped Weapon: %currentweapon%
echo.
echo Weapons:
echo.
if %sword1%==true echo 1- Tachi && set /a anyweps=true
if %anyweps%==false echo You have no weapons.

set /p equip="Enter the number here:"
if %equip%==1 if %sword1%==true set /a currentweapon=Tachi
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
set /a anyweps=true
```

same here: `set /a currentweapon=Tachi`

`set /a` will set a number, `true` is not a number, so the variable will be "0"  (Numbers equivalent to a empty string).

Just remove the `/a`.

Keep in mind: for strings, use `set "var=string"`, for doing arithmetics use `set /a var=5+2`